# ¿Cómo hago para que un Map utilizado en un objeto se limpie al momento de ser utilizado en otro objeto diferente? JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, hashmap

Hola estoy trabajando con un Jtable y lo que pasa es que estoy ingresando al mismo diferentes objetos de la clase Factura. Hasta ahí todo bien, el lío se presenta cuando luego quiero vaciar el Map, que me permite ir guardando de manera temporal los distintos productos agregados y su respectiva cantidad, para iniciar una nueva factura y así que no se vayan como "sumando" los productos entre un usuario y otro. Cuando coloco la línea `pCantidad.clear();` automáticamente aquello que se mostraba en el Jtable desaparece.

Este es básicamente el código que me permite ir generando nuevas facturas:

```
 private void realizarCompraButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
        String nombre = nombreClienteTextField.getText();
        String fecha = fechaTextField.getText();
        String mediopago = (String) medioPagoComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        double totalpagar = Double.parseDouble(totalPagarTextField.getText());

        if (!totalPagarTextField.getText().isBlank()
                & !nombreClienteTextField.getText().isBlank()
                & medioPagoComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            if (medioPagoComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                facturas.add(app.realizarVenta(nombre, fecha, false, cantidadTotalProductos, totalpagar,pCantidad));
                ventas.add(new Venta(nombre, fecha, mediopago, totalpagar));
                resetearCasillasTotal();
                datosIngresados.removeAllElements();
                pCantidad.clear();
                
            }
            if (medioPagoComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
                double abono = Double.parseDouble(abonoTextField.getText());
                debeTextField.setText(String.valueOf(totalpagar - abono));
                if (abonoTextField.getText().isBlank() & !numeroCuotas.getText().isBlank()) {
                    facturas.add(app.realizarVenta(nombre, fecha, false, cantidadTotalProductos, totalpagar,pCantidad));
                    ventas.add(new Venta(nombre, fecha, mediopago, totalpagar));
                    resetearCasillasTotal();
                    datosIngresados.removeAllElements();
                    pCantidad.clear();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor llenar todos los"
                            + "campos necesarios para continuar");
                }
            }
        
        } 
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor llenar todos los"
                    + "campos necesarios para continuar");
        }
        
    }
```

Y con este lo muestro en el Jtable:

```
public void verFacturas() {
        int i=0,contador=0,k=0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < facturas.size(); j++) {
                contador+=facturas.get(j).getMap().size();
        }
        String matriz[][] = new String[contador][8];
        
        while(facturas.size()>i){
            
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : facturas.get(i).getMap().entrySet()) {
                matriz[k][0] = Integer.toString(facturas.get(i).getIdFactura());
                matriz[k][1] = entry.getKey();
                int idProducto = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());
                int size = productos.size();
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (productos.get(j).getIdProducto() == idProducto) {
                        matriz[k][2]=productos.get(j).getNombre();
                    }
                }
                matriz[k][3] = entry.getValue();
                matriz[k][4] = facturas.get(i).getVendedor();
                matriz[k][5] = facturas.get(i).getCliente();
                matriz[k][6] = Integer.toString(facturas.get(i).getCantProducto());
                matriz[k][7] = facturas.get(i).getFecha();
                k++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y disposición :)

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Y cuál es el inconveniente?. ¿No es lo que buscas? que tu JTable se vacíe cuando se presente un nuevo cliente

Comment: Hola @EduardoJiménez uhh, lo que busco es que vayan mostrando los diferentes datos a medida que se vayan agregando nuevos, pero sin afectar los registros de los datos anteriormente agregados.